# .NET WinForms приложение на фону для быстрого запуска

Tags: .net, winforms

Есть одно приложение WinForms с множеством UI-элементов, запуск которого длится в некоторых случаях несколько секунд. Оптимировать особо нечего, тормозит один из «жирных» контролов для редактирования текста (наподобии MS Word) от третьего произоводителя (выявлено профайлером).

Приложение запускается клиентами часто и они жалуются.

Изучал ngen, дает небольшой прирост производительности, но этого недостаточно.

Есть идея сделать так, что бы приложение было запущено на фону, и по запуску отображать подготовленные невидимые формы.

Может кто делал что-то подобное? Как такое в общих чертах делается?

Comment: Вы проверяли этот `control`не тянет с сервера производителя код, или dll

Comment: Нет не тянет. Там помимо этот контрола (самая тяжелая часть) еще и своя обработка данных. В общем , многое суммируется. Приложение должно загружаться оооочень быстро. Другого выхода, как фоновая пре-загрузка я не вижу